# OneToMany association updates instead of insert

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity with one-to-many association to child entity.

The child entity has 2 columns as PK and one of the column is FK to the parent table.

mapping looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER ) 
@JoinColumn(name="USER_RESULT_SEQUENCES.USER_RESULT_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_RESULT_ID",     unique=true, insertable=true, updatable=false)
private List<UserResultSequence> sequences;
```

I create an instance of parent and add children instances to list and then try to save it to DB.

If child table is empty it inserts all children and it works perfectly. if the child table is not empty it updates existing rows!

I don't know why it updates instead of inserts, any ideas why this might happen??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should happen because the new parent that you have created, you are associating existing children to it. As long as there are new children added to the parent(children which do not exist in DB), this should not be an issue.

Comment: but, the child PK composed of 2 columns, so every row is unique!

What am I missing??

by the way, the parent PK is not mapped in the child entity because doing so makes Hibernate complaint about duplicate column.

Comment: is there a way to insert to parent table that has a unique column ('ID'), and also add it's complimentary children that have the same unique 'ID' as the parent and another column value which together form the PK of child table ??

I must have it like this otherwise I will have to do 1 insert for the parent then get its 'ID' value and then do batch insert to all children - that will contradict the idea of Hibernate!